# Using variable to access multidimensional $_POST

Tags: php, post

Consider this code:

```
$var = 'test';
$_POST[$test]; // equals $_POST['test']
```

How can I access with the same method this variable:

```
$_POST['test'][0];
```

`$var = 'test[0]';` clearly doesn't work.

## EDIT

Let me give a bit more information. I've got a class that builds a form.
An element is added like this:

```
//$form->set_element(type, name, defaultValue);
$form->set_element('text', 'tools', 'defaultValue');
```

This results into :

```
<input type="text" name="tools" value="defaultValue" />
```

In my class I set the value: if the form is posted, use that value, if not, use the default:

```
private function set_value( $name, $value='' ) {
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )
        return $_POST[$name];
    else 
        return $value;
}
```

When I want to add multiple "tools", I would like to use:

```
$form->set_element('text', 'tools[0]', 'defaultValue');
$form->set_element('text', 'tools[1]', 'defaultValue');
$form->set_element('text', 'tools[2]', 'defaultValue');
```

But in the set_value function
 that gives `$_POST['tools[0]']` instead of `$_POST['tools'][0]`

Comment: `$_POST[$test][$index]`

Comment: Like u_mulder said, just like any regular multi dimensional array

Comment: Please check my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any number of variables in `[]` to access what you need:

```
$test = 'test';
$index = 0;
var_dump($_POST[$test][$index]);

$test = 'test';
$index = 0;
$subkey = 'key'
var_dump($_POST[$test][$index][$subkey]);
```

And so on.

There's no special function to achieve what you want, so you should write something, for example:

```
$key = 'test[0]';
$base = strstr($key, '[', true); // returns `test`
$ob_pos = strpos($key, '[');
$cb_pos = strpos($key, ']');
$index = substr($key, $ob_pos + 1, $cb_pos - $ob_pos - 1);
var_dump($arr[$base][$index]);
```

## Edit by LinkinTED

```
$key = 'test[0]';
$base = $n = substr($name, 0, strpos($key, '[') );
preg_match_all('/\[([^\]]*)\]/', $key, $parts);
var_dump($arr[$base][$parts[1][0]]);
```

Comment: Thank you @u_mulder, your answer leaded me to my solution. I've added it to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

See how when you did `$_POST['test'][0];` you just added `[0]` to the end? As a separate reference.

You have to do that.

```
$_POST[$test][0];
```

If you need *both* parts in variables then you need to use multiple variables, or an array.

```
$var = Array( "test", "0" );
$_POST[$test[0]][$test[1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Each dimension of an array is called by specifying the `key` or `index` together with the array variable.

You can reference a 3 dimensional array's element by mentioning the 3 indexes of the array.

```
$value = $array['index']['index']['index'];
```

Like,

```
$billno = $array['customers']['history']['billno'];
```

You can also use variables which has the index values that can be used while specifying the array index.

```
$var1 = 'customers';
$var2 = 'history';
$var3 = 'billno';
$billno = $array[$var1][$var2][$var3];
```

Comment: `$_POST['tools[0]']` is not a multi dimensional array. You are just naming your index tools[0] in your code. Why not use `tools0`,`tools1` etc? Or is `tools` an `array`? But doesnt seems so from the code you added.

Comment: True, it is not. That is my problem. The input gets a name like this name="tools[0]" which result after posting the form to $_POST['tools'][0]... See my point?

Comment: Whats the output of `echo $_POST['tools[0]'];`

Comment: NULL, because it isn't set